# Effects of spin on neutron star's surface acceleration due to gravity

Tags: gravity, centripetal-force, neutron-stars

Could a neutron star have sufficient mass and spin so that the centripetal force acts opposite to gravity to make the effective acceleration due to gravity zero or close to 1g? What would happen to the matter at the surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because centripetal force acts towards the centre. You could be thinking of centrifugal force in which particles with more momentum take longer to change direction under the same force (this is why centrifuges separate different materials).A spinning neutron star will bulge in the middle because there is more momentum in the middle where the star spins faster and the neutrons follow a larger circle than their neighbours because they take longer to change direction than their neighbours.